# Is there anything that PHP with CodeIgniter can do, which Ruby on Rails 3 can't do?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, database, codeigniter

I and my partner are trying to develop a website, and we are arguing which language to use to build a website. We both have some experienced with PHP with Codeigniter 1.6++ as well as RoR, although my partner used rails when it was in RoR1, which now is RoR3.

He wants to use PHP with CodeIgniter because he knows whats going around more explicitly, while RoR does not seem to satisfy him.

I want to use RoR 3, because it takes less time, and there are many gems which I can use (devise for example).

He is kind of worrying that Ruby on Rails won't be easy to change some configuration in db or codes once the websites gets bigger and bigger.

I just hate to think about writing lines and lines of codes from the scratch with Codeigniter within 2 months.. although I think it was not easy to manage db tables, once things got settled in rails..

So, I have been wondering.. is there any big advantage one from the other?

Comment: My inclination is to avoid PHP like the plague; it puts too much burden on the user for safe database access (magic quotes?! how many web pages have you seen with '' or \'\' or other stupid things?) or encoding HTML from untrusted sources for output to users. And I fixed way too many register globals bugs in php scripts to forgive the language -- nevermind it has been depricated for ages. The PHP dev team asked Linux distro vendors to stop including "interpreter crash" bugs in security updates because they fixed roughly one each week. No sir, I've got no happy feelings towards PHP.

Comment: This comment makes me feel guilty for using php

Comment: @sarnold: Not all PHP is bad, most decent PHP developers do not use any of those aspects of the language.  A language should not be held accountable for poor usage of it by idiots, it has changed, moved on; outmoded opinions should be deprecated too.

Comment: @Orbling it is definitely true the C++ I learned doesn't exist any longer :) and thankfully the PHP team has deprecated the worst of their atrocities, but it is _really_ hard to try to force good design years after the product shipped.. :)

Comment: @sarnold: True, but like with most languages, the quality of the code written is more a matter of the skill of the userbase than the language itself.  Some languages attract a lot of inexperienced trainees, some tend to attract seasoned professionals.  PHP is very much in the former category due to a large number of reasons, most notably, ease of use (for a beginner; it is very forgiving) and ubiquitousness.

Comment: @orbling: another stacker here recently posted some PHP with _two_ weaknesses and _three_ remotely exploitable SQL injections in nine lines of code. I would NEVER use the phrase "for a beginner; it is very forgiving" about PHP. PHP makes it very easy to compromise your customers' data in a blink of an eye. The simplest way to do something in PHP is all too often a security bug waiting to be exploited. The simplest way to do something in Ruby on Rails or Django is often the safest way to do that thing. PHP forgiving? About as forgiving as a loan shark, or mortgage lender. :)

Comment: @sarnold: A beginner should not have customers.  I meant forgiving in terms of getting results out of poor code, from a learning perspective.  Not production, safety-critical work, which should be undertaken by professionals.  Companies that do not wish to pay for professionals, get what they pay for.

Comment: @Orbling: too true, but I'm afraid the "hey look how easy PHP is!" approach to web programming without realizing that, in fact, one is juggling chain saws, is more on the problem side than on the solution side of the situation.

Comment: @sarnold: Short of licensing publicly visible websites so that only qualified professionals can make a site publicly visible, there is not much that could be done.  The horse has bolted.

Comment: @Orbling: don't give up hope! We can still encourage new developers to learn kinder, gentler languages, such as RoR or Django, so that the _next_ generation of programmers won't have to fight against their development language just to write safe programs. It took a few decades, but Python, Ruby, Java, C# (and to some extent, modern C++) all have drastically reduced the number of unsafe memory problems that C introduced. Better languages will eventually replace PHP, we just need to make sure people know about the alternatives. :)

Comment: @sarnold: I don't think they are better for beginners, not without training; the concepts are quite advanced.  PHP is quite good for entry level learners, when they are still trying to understand for-loops and if().  I wrote a long piece on a related question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21048/is-a-php-a-good-language-to-start-with/21057#21057

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an avid user of both I would not say that this is a question of which framework is better or worse as they are apples and oranges.

CodeIgniter has not changed all that much since 1.6.x both of your experience is still valid and you will be able to code right from the get-go.

Rails 3 is wonderful but quite a lot has changed since Rails 1 (not that I was using it back then). I think your partner would have too much time scratching his head unless you are going to be there for him to constantly answer the WTF's that will inevitably come up.

To explain, I am a CodeIgniter man and have been for years. There is not much to it, no conventions and what code is there is simple, easy to extend and easy to ignore  if you don't like it.

Recently starting working with Rails has been a great series of highs and lows but it's not always quicker. I spent 2 hours implementing a fully functional user system with fb, twitter, etc and had most of my controllers built, but since then I have spent hours trying to get various date formats to play nicely with the ActiveRecord, or trying to override create_at, manually set id's and all the other stuff that nobody ever mentions you are not allowed to do.

If you need to pump out some code fast then Rails might be an option. If you want fine grained control over everything and have a really lightweight base to build your application on then CodeIgniter really would be a better choice.

Or, look at [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com) which is a framework me and a few others are working on to combine the two into one Configuration over Convention framework with a command line utility to bring in some of Rails best features. Saves a fair bit of code and you'll feel right at home.

Comment: A good answer.  Pointing out that whilst some hard bits in one may go fast in another; some of the easy bits may then go slow.  A mixed bag.

Answer (score 3):

You can make most languages do most things at the end of the day, just a matter of how long it'll take you.

Hopefully you know your project well enough to know what the major stumbling blocks are liable to be and then match them against your combined knowledge to solve them within both languages.  Which ever you both feel more comfortable with overall should win.  You will be able to do it in either, just a matter of familiarity and confidence with the language (as well as availability of libraries for complex tasks).

Incidentally, this question would be better on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just because your answer isn't language specific, the question is.  I think it's right at home here on SO.

Comment: And I for one lament the growing fragmentation of our community.

Answer (score 1):

From a management perspective, I can tell you that if you plan on growing in the future, you will pay twice as much and have to look twice as long for RoR programmers.  PHP programmers on the other hand are easy to find and hire since the language is ubiquitous.  I have known of companies that were bought and their product completely folded just to recruit the Ruby talent because it is so hard to find.